# Can we put a constant sequence ? for example : $U_n = a$ where a is a real number

Tags: sequences-and-series

i found a question that asks to say whether the proposition is True or False and prove it if it is True and give a counter example if it is false, so they said if a sequence is converge to 0 then it's monotonous so i think it's False and i wanted to give as counter example this sequence $U_n = 0$

Comment: Well, a constant sequence is monotonous, so that isn't a counterexample. The statement is false, though. Consider the sequence $(-2)^{-n}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that $U_{n}$ does indeed converge to $0$. However, your alleged counter example in fact is a positive example, because your sequence is indeed monotonous by definition:

$U_{n} monotonous :\iff (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}:U_{n} \leq U_{n+1} \lor  \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: U_{n+1} \leq U_{n}) $

In other words, the statement talks about monotonous, not **strictly** monotonous. A constant series is both monotonically increasing as well as monotonically decreasing.

Try to find a series that is indeed neither but still converges. Hint: it may involve $(-1)^n$. Spoiler:

> Consider $U_{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$